# Android : ProGuard cannot find setter for attribute "bind:items" in recycler view inside layout

Tags: android, android-proguard, android-databinding

Compile time error occurs when I try to run with ProGuard and data binding enabled.

Note : Same code works when proGuard is disabled.

Here is the console error message

> Cannot find the setter for attribute `'bind:itemOrders'` with
>   parameter type `java.util.List<com.example.boss.ItemOrder>` on
>   `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`.

Here is my layout where I bind recycler view using bind attribute.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.boss.BossViewModel" />
    </data>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/itemOrderRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                style="@style/ItemOrders"
                bind:itemOrders="@{viewModel.itemOrders}"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Here is my custom data binding method

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:itemOrders")
public static void bindList(RecyclerView view, List<ItemOrder> itemOrders) {
    view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
    view.setAdapter(new ItemOrderAdapter(itemOrders));
}
```

Here is my proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keepclassmembers public class com.example.boss.BossViewModel{*;}
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }    
-keepattributes *Annotation*    
-keepattributes javax.xml.bind.annotation.*    
-keepattributes javax.annotation.processing.*  

-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @android.databinding.BindingAdapter public *;
}

-dontwarn android.databinding.**
```

Comment: You should be using `@BindingAdapter("itemOrders")` instead of `@BindingAdapter("bind:itemOrders")`

Comment: @blizzard thnx, i have tried it but not luck also plz note that the same code works when proGuard is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change namespace shcema from

```
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to

```
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/tools"
```

Also, you can remove *bind* prefix from `@BindingAdapter` definition - this name space will be ignored.